# Sublime - set text size to 2 on new files?

Tags: sublimetext

I already have the following setting in **Preferences -> Settings - User**

```
{
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
  "tabSize":2,
  "detect_indentation": false
}
```

However opening a new file and hitting tab still indents 4 spaces. How can I make Sublime indent 2 spaces on new files?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you didn't correctly spell tab size :

```
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings",
// and are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
{
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

I tried this on Sublime and it works like a charm.

see here : http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html